# How to center text horizontally within beamer column?

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment

I've got a frame in beamer with two columns. Each column contains a figure that contains an image. I'd like to put some text below each figure.

I'd like the text to be centred within each column.

This is what my frame looks like:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Auswirkung der Knotenzahl}
\begin{columns}
\column{6.5cm}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=.90\textwidth]{KnotNo_1}
\end{figure}
Underfitting/Oversmoothing
\column{6.5cm}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=.90\textwidth]{KnotNo_3}
\end{figure}
Overfitting/Undersmoothing
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

I've tried putting the text inside a center environment but that doesn't give me the result I want (i.e. the text isn't perfectly aligned within each column).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Simply use the `\centering` declaration in each column.

Comment: Using `figure` environments here doesn't really make sense. You should get rid of them.

Comment: The reason I used figure was to get the text below the images. Without using it the images cover part of the text.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. See my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you need `figure` environments, here.

To centre everything within one column, just use the `\centering` declaration in it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz} % used instead of graphicx, for exposition purposes

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Auswirkung der Knotenzahl}
\begin{columns}
\column{6.5cm}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path[draw=red,fill=red!20] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
Underfitting/Oversmoothing
\column{6.5cm}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path[draw=blue,fill=blue!20] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
 \end{tikzpicture}
Overfitting/Undersmoothing
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd forgotten the empty lines around the text. This does make much more sense. Thank you!

Comment: @user2249626 Empty lines around the text don't change anything in this case. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 2):

The `center` environment centers the text correctly, but it looks misaligned because the images above *aren't* centered. You can add `\centering` to each figure to fix it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Auswirkung der Knotenzahl}
  \begin{columns}
    \column{6.5cm}
    \begin{figure}
      \centering
      \tikz{\fill (0,0) rectangle (1,1);}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{center}
      Underfitting/Oversmoothing
    \end{center}
    \column{6.5cm}
    \begin{figure}
      \centering
      \tikz{\fill (0,0) rectangle (1,1);}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{center}
      Overfitting/Undersmoothing
    \end{center}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]